# What does "幸せじゃない大人に説得力あるものか" mean?

Tags: translation

I'm not Japanese and I was chatting with my Japanese teenager niece in English about her school life and bullying, and I said, "Don't worry, things will get better".

She answered in Japanese with "Shiawase ja nai otona ni settoku ryoku aru mono ka" (幸せじゃない大人に説得力あるものか).

What does that mean?

I'm a beginner in Japanese, so I don't really get what she said. Did she criticize me or something? Some people started laughing... I'm so confused.

Thanks.

Comment: If that is something your niece actually said to you, how come it's all over the internet?  https://search.yahoo.co.jp/search;_ylt=A7dPCzxILntZnRsAHE.JBtF7?p=%E2%80%9D%E5%B9%B8%E3%81%9B%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E5%A4%A7%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AB%E8%AA%AC%E5%BE%97%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B%E2%80%9D&search.x=1&fr=top_ga1_sa&tid=top_ga1_sa&ei=UTF-8&aq=-1&oq=%22%E5%B9%B8%E3%81%9B%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E5%A4%A7%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AB%E8%AA%AC%E5%BE%97%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B%22&at=&aa=&ai=cit5fE.URrO_B2dZndK.7A&ts=3026

Comment: I read the search results (or tried) and what she said is the title or a verse of some song, right? After reading mackygoo's answer and thinking about the context of the chat, I think she used it to criticize me somewhat. Thanks for letting me know about it!

Answer (score 2):

> "Shiawase ja nai otona ni settoku ryoku aru mono ka" (幸せじゃない大人に説得力あるものか).

With my poor trial, it could be said like "<del>*Words are not persuasive said by a not so happy adult like you!*</del> *It's impossible that what is said by an unhappy adult like you is persuasive!*"

She is somewhat criticizing you.
I'm sure she knows you have not succeeded in life or you are not so happy.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: The word itself is ambiguous because the に can be taken as indicating either the recipient of the persuasion or the possessor of the persuasiveness. But from the context, well, you got it correct.. but I think nothing to worry about. :)

Comment: @karlalou: Yes, "に" could be taken as both ways. As you know, I took it as indicating the possessor of the persuasiveness. Thank you for your explanation!